# Create and Search in Nested Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I want to create nested DataTables where the nested table's data is associated with parent table. While trying to search any data, data of both parent & nested tables should also be checked and searched for match.

Example:

```
Ticket List.                 Search:_________


Ticket No  |  Holder Name | Amount

-----------|--------------|----------

32415.     | ABC.         | ₹345
37524.     | BKC.         | ₹456

- Grp1
   45732.  | RDC.         | ₹953
   42156.  | TED.         | ₹741

- Grp2
   38521.  | HUW.         | ₹523
   37254.  | TWH.         | ₹423
```

Now, I should be able to search grouped and ungrouped ticket no using only one search box(which is at the top). I.e. searching of 32415, 38521, etc should be possible with one search box.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Is java or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are searching for something like [RowGroup](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/). It's a Datatable.js Extension. In the examples you can see this [basic Initialization](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/simple.html), where they only passed the `rowGroup` object in the initialization to inform the RowGroup. From the example, the default search feature seems to include both group and sub group rows.

Keep in mind these limitations, quoted from [RowGroup documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/):

> The features offered by RowGroup are useful, but also also limited in several aspects. The following limitations are known and will be topics for future updates (there is no time for these features yet):
>
> - No option to expand / collapse a group
> - Currently only a single data point can be used for grouping at a time there is no support for nested grouping
> - Click and drag column headers to group
> - No support for the export options of the Buttons extension the grouping information is just
>     ignored
> - No support for the Scroller extension.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the solution seems to group the data and then allow searching on it.. That is not what I am looking for... I will modify my query with more realistic data...

Comment: Ok, i see that this approach will not help. I don't know if you already searched for this in Datatables documentation, but the only thing close to what you need that i could find there is [Child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), but is just an approach to make a detailed table for each row and the search criteria don't include in the nested tables.